# Were covered wagons used on the Federal Road in North GA in the early 1830's?

Tags: united-states

I'm doing reasearch on the years leading up to the Cherokee removal and need to know if pioneers during the early 1830's used covered wagons to travel long distances on the Federal Road in north Georgia.

Comment: As you're new on Stack Exchange and this likely is homework, FYI it's usually best to show what you've found so far in your question. Many history-related questions can be reasonably answered with a few google searches that dip into reasonable sources. For instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covered_wagon offers that "covered wagon was long the dominant form of transport in pre-industrial America" and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgia_(U.S._state) offers that the Cherokee were displaced at the time owing to a gold rush, so it's sensible to assume that covered wagons were used indeed.

Comment: My goodness, Denis, it has been a long, long time since I had homework! This is for research on a book of fiction I plan to write about the time prior to the removal. My child character would travel from Athens to the Calhoun area (New Echota) and I couldn't find any source to tell me if COVERED wagons were used on the Federal Road in that area, although I know they traveled in wagons, stagecoaches and by horseback. A writer has to be absolutely certain of the information we use. Thank you for the links. I will certainly follow up.

Comment: Haha, no offense intended, I hope you didn't take it too badly. Hopefully the links will help you. And happy writing!

Answer (score 1):

[Covered wagons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covered_wagon) were used in pre-railroad times (up to about 1850) to travel rough, undeveloped roads in the United States, particularly in hilly areas.

[Old Federal Road](http://www.aboutnorthgeorgia.com/ang/Old_Federal_Road)in North Georgia was such a road, at the southern end of the Appalachians, and would have been travelled in the 1830s.